# SSIS 2012 - Impossible to use a custom dll

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, dll, ssis

I'm trying to use a custom .NET DLL I've developed using Visual Studio 2012. I've installed the DLL in the GAC folder with no issue. I'm just using a script task object. When I'm trying to instantiate a class from this dll, I'm getting an error saying that it's impossible to load the script... Here's the blocking line :

```
    AmadeusWebServices.Queries q = new AmadeusWebServices.Queries();
```

I really don't understand what I should do... The version of the .NET framework I used for the DLL is the 4.0 version so I think there is not issue with that...

Please help! Thanks !

EDIT : the error message is very generic ... :

> SSIS DTS Script Task has encountered an exception in user code 
>   Cannot load script for execution

Nothing more.

Comment: please, add error message

Comment: It's done but not relevant info...

Comment: May be this can help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15165760/ssis-script-task-fails-on-server-with-error-cannot-load-script-for-execution